# Xcode SDK version for testing & release?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am just putting the finishing touches to an iPhone app that I have written, signed up to the developer program and installed Xcode 3.2.2 (1650) My question is which version of the SDK should I be using to build my application? I was thinking I should be using the latest 3.2 but when I select that I can only access the iPad simulator ...

[image]

Should I be using 3.1.3 which runs the iPhone simulator. (NB: I originally developed the app in 3.1.2

cheers gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone OS 3.2 only runs on the iPad, the current version for the iPhone is 3.1.3.